# Problemas al conectar Java producer a Kafka por WAN

Tags: java, kafka

estoy intentado conectar un productor java a un servidor por su IP pública, donde está kafka esperando.

Si hago esto mismo por LAN, funciona perfectamente. Pero si lo hago por WAN, recibo este mensaje:

> Disconnection from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout.

Ya he comprobado que hago ping al servidor y que está escuchando en el puerto.